# How to center text vertically in a TextView with Java code?

Tags: java, android, textview, alignment

I know this question has been asked many times on SO. I have read most of them,  but they don't work for me, so don't bother marking duplicates.

Here is my code, and what I have tried so far:

```
RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());

TextView tv = new TextView(this.getContext());
tv.setText(txt); // a single digit like '3'
tv.setLines(1);
tv.layout(0, offsety, cellszie, offsety+cellsize);

tv.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

// I also tried CENTER_VERTIAL and the following line
// tv.setGravity(CENTER_VERTIAL| CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

// I also tried giving LayoutParams to tv like this:
// tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(cellsize, cellsize));
// tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
// tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));

container.addView(tv);
```

The character is horizontally centered, but it floats on the top of the TextView vertically. Setting `gravity` and `LayoutParams` doesn't change its behavior.

What should I do to make it center vertically?

Comment: Did you tried making its width and height as wrap_content?

Comment: try this http://code2care.org/pages/center-align-textview-android-horizontally-or-vertically/

Comment: set layout params and set height to match parent.. then center_vertical will work

Comment: @R.R.M I have tried both `wrap_content` and `match_parent`.

Comment: Ok then try to set relativeLayout's params as match_parent

Answer (score 1):

use this class for VerticalTextView.

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {
final boolean topDown;

public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    final int gravity = getGravity();
    if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
        setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
        topDown = false;
    }else
        topDown = true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
    textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

    canvas.save();

    if(topDown){
        canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
        canvas.rotate(90);
    }else {
        canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
        canvas.rotate(-90);
    }
    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

    getLayout().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_file, null);
container.addView(view);
```

where R.layout.my_layout_file contains textview with gravity center. and here you can get object of textview like this

```
textviewObject = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** to you RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
container.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams)
```

Then set the gravity for your TextView:

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Then add the view to your RelativeLayout:

```
container.addView(tv);
```